# Using Sinon to mock a constant/variable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm fairly new to testing and even newer to Sinon.

Here I have an express route set up:

```
import context = require("aws-lambda-mock-context");

this.router.post('/', this.entryPoint);

public entryPoint(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const ctx = context();
    alexaService.execute(req.body, ctx);
    ctx.Promise
        .then((resp: Response) => res.status(200).json(resp))
        .catch((err: Error) => res.status(500));
}
```

My aim is to test that the post call to `/` runs appropriately. My test script is:

```
describe('/POST /', () => {
    it('should post', () => {
        chai.request(app)
            .post('/v2')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.be.ok;
            });
    });
});
```

Though my test passes it returns `status: 500` due to the `const ctx = context()` not being recognized. Is there an appropriate/correct way to spy on the variable `ctx` and return a mock variable within my test using Sinon? I've been spinning my wheels here for so long.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem which I've come accross myself. I've tested multiple solutions, the one I've found to work best is [Mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery).

It works like this: before you require your module under test, you tell Mockery to substitute modules the module under test requires with mocks.

For your code, it would look something like this:

```
const mockery = require('mockery');
const { spy } = require('sinon');

describe('/POST /', () => {
    let ctxSpy;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockery.enable({
            useCleanCache: true,
            warnOnUnregistered: false
        });
        ctxSpy = spy();
        mockery.registerMock('"aws-lambda-mock-context"', ctxSpy);

        // change this to require the module under test
        const myRouterModule = require('my-router-module'); 

        myRouterModule.entryPoint({}, {}, () => {});
        return ctxSpy;
    });

    it('should call ctx', () => {
        expect(ctxSpy).called.to.be.ok;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        mockery.deregisterAll();
        mockery.disable();
    });
});
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I suggest you use `mockery.registerAllowable` before requiring your module under test :)

Comment: Right, forgot to mention that because I had hidden that away in my setup.